# does buffering take clock cycles in microcontrollers?"

Tags: memory, buffer, microcontroller

I've been wondering how buffering works for microcontrollers. Essentially, I am using a temperature probe where I am samplying around 50hz.

If I buffer 50 samples, then do processing on the 50 samples; rinse an drepeat for 10 000 samples, will I be missing samples? Essentially does buffering happen in parallel or can a simple microcontroller (atmega328 as an example) do either or?

Can I still buffer data in from the sensor when I am manipulating and processing data?

Comment: all these questions are "it depends"  is it possible for all those things to happen, sure there are probably designs.  how does that specific part work?  read the manual.  Some can do dma into a buffer which is often not "in parallel" but if you do your system design and some tests you can figure out if you have enough bandwidth.  also is there a way to ping pong the buffers, be processing half the buffer space while the peripheral is grabbing the other half?  read the manual.

Comment: you can do tests assuming you have real-ish data in memory just run the processing half of it, how fast does that code run? is it close to the margin if so then when the dma engine or whatever else is gathering data you probably cant do this at that rate.

Comment: there is no single design solution that everyone uses, it is implementation defined so it depends on the specific vendor/chip/peripheral plus some other factors depending on those.

Comment: to your title question it all takes clock cycles, it takes clock cycles to do the sampling, takes clock cycles to move the data and takes clock cycles to store the data, how many overall to do some amount of data?  it depends read the manual or do some experiments.